# Search is not running on pagination

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

When i have to search any thing it gives me the right sesrch but when i click page 2 to navigate for showing more records it does not show thw right results. In short i applied paginatiion on it but after click on second page the search query does not run only simple query runs. Please tell me which is the issue?

```
    <form method="post" action=""><input type='textbox' name="searchfield" id='searchfield' $value style='height:25px; width:275px; border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px; margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:50px;' />    <input type="submit" id='GetBtn' name="GetBtn" class='GetBtn' value="Search"></form>

    <?php 

    if(isset($_GET['GetBtn'])){
         $match = str_replace('-',' ',slugify($_POST['searchfield']));

       $query_pag_data = "SELECT * FROM `imported_deals` WHERE MATCH ( `Name`, `Category` )
AGAINST ('$match' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

    }
     else{   
    $query_pag_data = "SELECT * FROM `imported_deals` LIMIT $per_page ( `Name`, `Category` ) 
AGAINST ('$match' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
     }

     $PAGING        =   new PAGING($query_pag_data,10);
    $query          =   $PAGING->sql;
    $res                =   mysql_query($query);
    if(!$res) die(mysql_error());


    if($show['subcat_name'] != '')
        {
             echo($PAGING->show_paging("http://yespricer.com/","deals/".slugify($fullname)."/".slugify($show['subcat_name'])."/page")); 
        }
        else
        {
             echo($PAGING->show_paging("http://yespricer.com/","deals/".slugify($fullname)."/page")); 
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever values you are getting from the post, store them in hidden fields in form and push them as get/post data to second page.